# Using PHP within the TinyMCE editor bad practice?

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I believed that using PHP within the TinyMCE editor to be bad practice but cannot find any confirmation on such a thing. So I'm turning it over to more experienced programmers to advise anyone thinking of such a practice.

Cons:

1. Output may be undesirable
2. Possible security vulnerabilities
3. Impossible for non-coders to maintain

Pros:

1. Preference in development for some

Comment: TinyMCE won't even allow it, so why do you ask? The security vulnerabilities associated with allowing it are not "possible" but absolutely certain.

Comment: I ask because I'm fixing a website where the developers did in fact use PHP within the MCE editor. What's with the DV's?

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely difficult to validate user input which contains PHP code because there are so very many different ways to be malicious on the server side, even with a very limited set of allowed instructions. Regardless of how you accept the user-generated PHP code (i.e. via TinyMCE or otherwise), executing it directly on the server is a very dangerous practice. The only context in which this would be less dangerous is if you completely trust each and every one of your users, and in this case it's still not a good practice. I cannot think of a single case in which you would need to do this.

Comment: Thanks for responding properly! Please feel to elaborate. The more the better.

Answer (score 0):

It is far easier to post your Root Password on the web, to help avoid wondering where exactly you were hacked.

Dont try to run PHP through MCE, extend via use of custom Functions as Matt the WP God intended.